# Redirecting 404s using 301 redirects with .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

The .htaccess file I'm editing contains the following code for redirecting http://www.example.com to http://example.com:

```
AddHandler fcgid54-script .php
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Without writing a new .htaccess file from scratch, I'm looking to redirect a few other pages that are returning 404s. I tried the following but it didn't work:

```
AddHandler fcgid54-script .php
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

301 Redirect /blank/blah/page/ http://example.org/blank/blah/

# END WordPress
```

I've also tried a bunch of other other iterations, but nothing is working so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't mix `mod_rewrite` rules with `mod_alias` ones and keep 301 before internal WP rule:

```
AddHandler fcgid54-script .php
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^blank/blah/page/?$ http://example.org/blank/blah/ [L,NC,R=301]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

**try this it will work :**

```
ErrorDocument 404 http://www.example.com/abc.html
```

By adding this line in `htaccess` file, pages that are returning 404s are forwarded to the specified url. such as `http://www.example.com/abc.html`